# issue in magento connect magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

there is an issue in my Magento connect 
first when I try to enter it shows like this http://prntscr.com/hzub6a
and when I enter it shows this http://prntscr.com/hzubks

anyone knows what's the problem here? Magento 1.9

Comment: Check the page source when you open Magento Connect and try to open one css file that is trying to be loaded, then post what the response is. For some reason the site's css isn't loading properly.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm not that experience. do you mean this? http://prntscr.com/hzvk8t

I clicked right in mouse and choose View Source

Comment: Yep, now click the skin/boxes.css link and see what it says

Comment: Hi, sorry for late, it show this http://prntscr.com/i06pj1

Answer (score 0):

Check the file `/downloader/skin/boxes.css` through cPanel or FTP software.

It should have permissions set at 644. You can usually edit the permissions by right clicking the file and changing them.

If the permissions are correct (at least 644), check the `/downloader/` folder for the `.htaccess` file.

Change its contets to:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    RemoveOutputFilter DEFLATE
    RemoveOutputFilter GZIP

</IfModule>

<Files ~ "\.(cfg|ini|xml)$">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Make sure you backup the original .htaccess file in case it has additional modifications you might need later.

Comment: Hi, I do that but still http://prntscr.com/i14r1p
I cleat cache as well

Comment: Try checking the `/downloader/` and `/downloader/skin/` folder permissions as well. They should be set at `755`